# Get records not in table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables: Member, Meeting and Member_Meeting. The names alone should give away what they contain. Member is for registered members, Meeting is for past and future meetings and Member_Meeting is for members who have or will be attending meetings. I can use inner joins to get data in both tables, left joins to get data in both but also on the left, right joins to get data in both but also on the right and (full) outer joins to get data from both and right and left. What I need however is data that only exists in Member but not in Member_Meeting. In other words, I need to get all the members that exist but have not ever attended a meeting and therefore do not have a record in the Member_Meeting. What I need is sort of like a left join or a right join but without what the tables have in common.

Comment: So you're after the [`NOT IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) function?

Comment: How would you join the two tables with that (Member and Member_Meeting)?

Comment: select * from member where ... not in (select xyz from member_meeting), something like that I think

Comment: It would be something along the lines of `SELECT * FROM members WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT member_id FROM member_meeting )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this. The first is to do a subquery using `NOT IN()`:

```
SELECT * FROM Member WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT MemebrID FROM Member_Meeting)
```

The other option is to do a `LEFT JOIN` and then filter on the null values

```
SELECT Member.* FROM Member
LEFT JOIN Member_Meeting ON Member.ID = Member_Meeting.MemberID
WHERE Member_Meeting.MemberID IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure if recent MySQL versions have fixed the performance issues with subqueries (in 5.1, the subquery was run for every row in the main query), so the join is probably faster.

Comment: It feels like there should be a keyword for this type of joins, like "ONLY LEFT JOIN" or something.